# Float to std::string conversion and localization

Tags: c++, decimal, locale

Does the conversion from float to std::string could be affected by current system locale?

I'm wondering if the above code could produce an output in the form of "1234,5678" instead of "1234.5678" under Germal locale for example:

```
std::string MyClass::doubleToString(double value) const
{
    char fmtbuf[256], buf[256];
    snprintf(fmtbuf, sizeof(fmtbuf)-1, "%s", getDoubleFormat().c_str());
    fmtbuf[sizeof(fmtbuf)-1] = 0;
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)-1, fmtbuf, value);
    buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = 0;

    return std::string(buf);
}

static std::string const& getDoubleFormat() { return "%f"; }
```

If yes, how to prevent this? How to have an output always in the form : "1234.5678" with the dot to separate the decimals?

Comment: the web has the answer :] http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf yes it's locale dependent, so to prevent this change the locale like http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/locale_h/setlocale.php. If you use c++11 use std::to_string etc

Comment: Does the `std::to_string` function is locale independent? Does it return a double always in the form "1234.5678" despite of the current locale setting?

Comment: To_string is also locale dependent. But it gets rid of the typical snprintf mess and completely replaces your doubleToString so it's definitely worth using

Comment: What I can't figure out is why the locale is not a parameter of `std::to_string` for example. In a multi-thread environment, if my function above is wrapped with a `setLocale()` and `restoreLocale()` also other parts of my application are affected too by this locale change...

Comment: POSIX lets you change the locale per-thread, see [uselocale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html)

Comment: Why that is is rather out of scope here (msvc does have support for per-thread locale afaik). My guess: backwards compatibility, std library didn't used to know about threads etc. But streams allow setting locale on them so you could use that instead.

Comment: @stijn, `to_string` is new in C++11 so there is no backwards compatibility issue. It's just meant to be a simple wrapper around `sprintf`, but as soon as you involve locales it stops being simple.

Comment: I passed by and my remark is as such: I needed an answer why in a windows forms a casuallye coded marshal_as<String^>(to_string(double)) produced something that Convert::ToDouble() produced an answer as if the decimals point had not been there. to_string() obviously has different rules than Convert::ToString(), which solved this weird problem

Answer (score 2):

The **[`<locale>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/)** localization of the standard C library affects 
formatted input / output operations with its character transformation rules and decimal - point character set in the numeric formatting settings.

```
// On program startup, the locale selected is the "C" standard locale, (equivalent to english). 
printf("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL));
cout << doubleToString(3.14)<<endl;
// Switch to system specific locale 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");  // depends on your environment settings. 
printf("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL));
cout << doubleToString(3.14) << endl;
printf("Locale is: %c\n", localeconv()->thousands_sep);
printf("Decimal separator is: %s\n", localeconv()->decimal_point); // get the point
```

The result is:

```
Locale is: C
3.140000
Locale is: French_France.1252
3,140000
Decimal separator is: ,
```

If you opt for C++ formatting functions,  then there are the **[C++ `<locale>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/)** which are more powerful and flexible. Note however that the setting of the C locale doesn't influence the C++ locale:

```
cout << 3.14<<" "<<endl;   // it's still the "C" local 
cout.imbue(locale(""));    // you can set the locale only for one stream if desired
cout << 3.14 << " "<<1000000<< endl; // localized output
```

**Remark:**

There is a problem with the following:

```
static std::string const& getDoubleFormat() { return "%f"; }
```

The function shall return a reference to a string.  Unfortunately, you return a string literal `"%f"` which is of type `const char[3]`.  This means that there is an implicit conversion that will construct a temporary `string` from a `const char*` and return its reference.  But the temporary object gets destroyed at the end of the expression, so the reference returned is no longer valid !

For the test, I've returned by value.